# I'm trying to make cheddar sticks from scratch

Tags: cheese, deep-frying, breading

What are common commercial food additives that keep the cheese 'melty', but not runny?

I have tried making fried cheddar sticks but the cheese just oozes out, like thick water...

Freezing first?  Freeze the breading too?

Comment: What is the "cheddar stick" you are asking about?  One commercial product, such as this one from [Wegman's](http://www.wegmans.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?productId=722693&storeId=10052&langId=-1) appears to be 100% cheese, without special additives.  Are you asking about a recipe for deep fried cheese sticks?  If so, you might want to post the recipe to get advise on improving it.

Comment: The title says cheddar, the tag says mozzarella?

Comment: What temperature are you frying at? The cheese *will* melt but the batter should harden too fast for anything to leak out. And you *are* actually deep-frying, not just putting it in a fry pan, right?

Comment: Are we talking like these: http://www.hotdogonastick.com/menu.aspx (scroll down a bit)

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/93307/67

Answer (score 5):

Sodium Citrate is the most common emulsifier for cheese, it keeps it soft and flexible when cold, and like a smooth sauce when hot. Being an emulsifier it stops it separating too

See http://modernistcuisine.com/recipes/sodium-citrate-creates-silky-smooth-macaroni-and-cheese/

You can make Sodium Citrate at home, heat a tbs of lemon juice, add 1/2+ tsp of baking soda and stir. Add this to a cup of melted cheese (all very rough measurements). Experiment to get the best results for your cheese of choice!

Comment: Why haven't you told me about this before! I have some new experiments to do!

Comment: I always check the labels of the stuff in the Supermarket that I wont buy 'cause it's crap food, and check for what they use to make it that way :-) Some aren't that crap after all